# How to solve undefined constructor -error in passing arguments to a file?

Tags: java, file

I am having problems passing a file as an argument from class called `WordList` to main class and just printing the `ArrayList` of words to terminal. I can't pass the argument "Words" when calling the constructor because of "Cannot be resolved to a variable" -error. File path is okay, I have checked.

WordList class:

```
public class WordList{
    private List<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<>();
    File Words = new File("task/words");

    public WordList(File Words){
        this.Words = Words;
    }

    //Returns the words in the file as list
    public List<String> giveWords() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Words));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            wordlist.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        return wordlist;
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WordList wordlist = new WordList(); // Error happens here
        System.out.println(wordlist.giveWords());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line (in method `main` of class `Main`)

```java
WordList wordlist = new WordList();
```

to this

```java
WordList wordlist = new WordList(new File("task/words"));
```

When you call the constructor of class `WordList`, you must supply a `File`. The idea is that class `WordList` can handle **any** file, not just file *task/words*.